# Super+O and Super+Shift+O don't work in Ubuntu 18.04 and PhpStorm

Tags: hotkeys, ubuntu-18.04, phpstorm

I am using `PhpStorm` on `Ubuntu 18.04`.

I would like to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> shortcuts but I can't make PhpStorm register them, it behaves as though these keystrokes don't exist.

Does Ubuntu intercept them? Can't find any information on that. It seems that Ubuntu doesn't react to them anyway.

What is going on here?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Apparently Super+O is caught by Gnome, it is the shortcut key for the "orientation lock".  This can be disabled, but the shortcut stays there...